# Creating a new Audio element for each item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here - figured it would be pretty simple to create an array of audio source files into audio elements with their respective source at each index in the array

Audio Data

```
//audio
import Maj1 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_A_major_1.mp3"
import Maj2 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_B_major_1.mp3"
import Maj3 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_C_major_1.mp3"
import Maj4 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_D_major_1.mp3"
import Maj5 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_E_major_1.mp3"
import Maj6 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_F_major_1.mp3"
import Maj7 from "./sounds/Guitar_Chords_-_G_major_1.mp3"

// console.log(Maj1) 
const chordsArray = [Maj1, Maj2, Maj3, Maj4, Maj5, Maj6, Maj7]
console.log(chordsArray)
```

Then I tried with several different implementations of loops to create a new audio element for each of those

```
 chordsArray.forEach(chord => new Audio(chord))
```

or

```
for (const chord of chordsArray){
    new Audio(chord)
}

console.log(chordsArray)
```

Yet, the array stays the same every time I log it to the console. Before the loop as well as after, chordArray simply logs

```
["/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_A_major_1.ca041471.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_B_major_1.c1dec9e3.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_C_major_1.53f15357.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_D_major_1.ac2499ea.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_E_major_1.c2f26ec1.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_F_major_1.851a10ae.mp3", "/static/media/Guitar_Chords_-_G_major_1.a1f4fc25.mp3"]
```

and not an array of audio elements and their respective sources

How can I go about to create an array of audio elements? I want a user to be able to click on a letter and hear the sound for that chord  which was clicked

Comment: You're not creating a new array of `Audio` objects with `forEach`. Try `map` instead: `const audioArray = chordsArray.map(chord => new Audio(chord))`.

Comment: Well. that was exactly it... getting to caught up in everything I miss the obvious things. Thanks so much!